# how to call Class mainMethod of another MavenProject from a controller[dispatchServlet] or any java class?

Tags: java, maven, main-method

anyBody please share the knowledge.

i am facing this Exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

from this  project A

```
package com.demo.feed;
@WebServlet("/run")
public class ProjA {
  String[] args={};
  new com.om.demo.ProjB().main(args);
}
```

i have to call main method of maven Project B

```
package com.om.demo;
public class ProjB {
    public void main( String[] args )
    {
        hello();
    }
    static void hello() {
            System.out.println("some text");
        }
```

}

I tried these things adding project B to project A and after that on run configuration i have added classPath Variables..

Needed output in console : some text

Answer (score 0):

In the pom of Project A you will have to add Project B as a dependency and then try running.
Before running you should make sure to run `mvn clean install` on Project B

Comment: sorry for the update projectA is just a controller [MVC] .

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml in dependencies section of project which contains ProjA class, you have to put:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.om.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>projb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

where projb is project which contains class ProjB. And then do `mvn install` on project which contains ProjB class.